# Print a range of lines by line numbers across multiple files

Tags: bash, awk, sed, iteration, glob

For example:
Print all between two lines in sed is:

```
sed -n '30,40p' filename
```

But, when I use it as:

```
sed -n '30,40p' *
```

It only prints the lines between 30 and 40 of the first file.

**What about a bunch of files?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), `sed` doesn't reset line numbering across input files.
(*If* you have *GNU* `sed`, you can use the `-s` option - see bottom).

While you *could* use a *shell loop* to address this problem (`for f in *; sed ...; done`), it's more efficient to use a single `awk` command, where built-in variable `FNR` reflects the *input file-relative* line number (1-based):

```
awk 'FNR >= 30 && FNR <= 40' *
```

This solution is POSIX-compliant.

---

If you have *GNU* `sed`, use the `-s` option to restart line numbering for each input file:

```
sed -s -n '30,40p' *
```

Comment: Thank you too much

Comment: The GNU sed option is probably the best bet if you have GNU sed, otherwise you can also use xargs: `xargs -n1 sed -n '30,40p' < <(ls file*)`

Comment: @A.Danischewski: Your `xargs` command will break with filenames with embedded whitespace. You could use `xargs -0 -I {} sed -n '30,40p' {}  < <(printf '%s\0'' *)` for robustness, but there's really no tangible advantage over using a shell loop - either way you'll be calling `sed` once for each input file.

Comment: Yea, that wasn't meant to be an answer - I think I would probably use `find -exec` or `xargs` if I were trying to really make it robust.

Comment: @A.Danischewski: My proposed `xargs` command _is_ robust (except for the extraneous `'` after `\0'`); `find` is only needed if you want to recurse and/or exclude file-system items by type. Anyway, what this answer demonstrates is that there is no need for _multiple_ invocations of `awk` or GNU `sed` - neither an `xargs` nor a `find` solution would satisfy that criterion.

Comment: @A.Danischewski: On second thought: if `find` _is_ needed and GNU `sed` is also available, then the following is an efficient combination: `find ... -exec sed -s -n ... +`  - the `+` is crucial to ensure that `sed` is (typically) only called _once_. The same would work with the `awk` command.

Answer (score 3):

Try with a for-loop:

```
for i in ./*
do
 sed -n '30,40p' "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop

```
for i in */* # */* will do the recursion
do sed -n '30,40p' "$i" # double quote the variable to avoid word splitting
done
```

Alternatively, if you want more control with file selection, using `find`

```
find . -type f "*.txt" -exec sed -n '30,40p' {} \;
```

This will find recursively, all the files with `.txt` extension and pass it to `sed`.

Comment: I understand the OP wants only the files in one directory (so "recursively" in the title is wrong really.)